# React check if the event is bubbled/captured without using Ref

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-ref

this is the solution using refs

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";

function Bar() {
    const ref = useRef();
    return (
            <div
               ref={ref}
               onClick={(ev) => {
                  if (ev.target == ref.current) console.log("Target hit");
                }}
             >
              Click me, maybe <div>test</div>
            </div>
     );
}
```

> In the above solution, target is not hit when we click on test. Can we
> get the same output **without using refs**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `currentTarget` property of the event, which will always refer to the element it is registered on, as opposed to `target` which is the element that triggered it:

```
function Bar() {
    return (
            <div
               onClick={(ev) => {
                  if (ev.target === ev.currentTarget) console.log("Target hit");
                }}
             >
              Click me, maybe <div>test</div>
            </div>
     );
}
```